# MVC How to call controller post method

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Hi I am pretty new to web development and am stuck on a specific scenario.

I have a Map controller with 2 methods:

```
public ActionResult Map1(double easting, double northing)
public ActionResult Map2(double easting, double northing)
```

When called they both navigate their corresponding view with whatever model is required:

```
return View(model);
```

I then have some javascript which needs to call the corresponding controller method depending on the action passed through.

I want to mark the controller methods as [HttpPost], but when I do this then use an ajax request in the javascript the call to the View gets swallowed and the page is not redirected.

Currently the only way I have got it to work is by this:

```
window.location.href = '/Map/' + actionVal + '?easting=' + easting + '&northing=' + northing;
```

But with using this I cannot set the methods as POST.

Does anyone have a better idea of how I should do this?

Comment: Ajax calls stay on the same page. From your comments to other answers I suspect you are not understanding GET and POST. Why do you need to make the method `[HttpPost]`

Comment: Ah ok, well that makes more sense that ajax calls stay on the same page, this obviously is not the right method for my scenario then as I want to go to a different page depending on the action passed through

Comment: @NAJ, To go to another view, please check my answer.

Comment: Thanks @ramiramilu your answer is looking more promising for what I am after, just not sure what I put in my javascript method to initiate the submit of the form?

Comment: a simple `$("$FormId").submit();` would submit the form of that Id.

Comment: You don't need to put anything in javascipt if you have a form with a submit button (it post the values of your inputs to the method! What does your `Map1` method do.

Comment: Just out of interest, does anyone know why would my question have been downvoted? I thought it was a valid scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does anyone have a better idea of how I should do this?

Actually there is no need for you to have `TWO` different Controller actions, instead you can have only `ONE`. And this action is going to return a view which you want to display.

One way to make a POST is to use `HTML.BeginForm()` and pass Controller and Action names along with `FormMethod.POST` to BeginForm(). Inside the BeginForm, you can have a HTML Input Button of type Submit to make the POST call to Controller action.

Also if you want to differentiate the invocation of this controller action, I would suggest you something like this -

First construct you model like this with `Type` variable through which you can differentiate the operation you need to perform on data -

```
public class Details
{
    public string easting { get; set; }
    public string northing { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}
```

And let your controller action be defined like this -

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Map(Details details)
```

And you can have your view define a `HiddenField` like this -

```
@model Namespace.Details

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Title";
}

<div id="uploadCourseList">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @* Other properties of Model *@
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.type)
        <input type="submit">
    }
</div>
```

Now on the view set the `type`, so that you can differentiate the post operation and perform necessary calculations on your data and return the view.

Comment: But how do I do the `HTML.BeginForm()` in the javascipt method?

Comment: Why do you want to make the `POST` using JAvaSCript method?

Comment: Awesome thanks so much @ramiramilu I now have it working, I apologise if I confused anyone, but as I said I am pretty new to web development so learning as I go

Comment: @NAJ Your question title is with javascript but this solution  don't use javascript!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: But I am, I am initiating the request from a javascript method and thanks to @ramiramilu the `$("$FormId").submit();` syntax has done the trick

Answer (score 4):

you can use  this code:

```
//Client Side
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("FirstAjax", "AjaxTest")',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: {id :1},
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(result) {
    alert(result);
    window.locationre=result.url;
    }
    });
//AjaxTest Controller
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult FirstAjax(string id)
{

 return Json(new {url="URL"});

}
```

Comment: I am trying your answer, but it doesn't hit the controller method, I have the url as `url: '@Url.Action("'+actionVal+'", "Map")',`

Comment: If I take the [HttpPost] attribute off the controller method and the type: POST from the ajax request it now hits the method, but it is not redirecting to the view, do you have any ideas?

Comment: @NAJ I update my answer.in ajax mode you cant redirect  from your controller.you can send your url to client and redirect with javascript " window.locationre" .check my answer please.

Answer (score 1):

You are sending a **GET** request. Because you are mapping your parameters on the *queryString*.

If you want to use it like that you should add the `[HttpGet]` attribute to the action. But I'd rather recomend you to use **HttpPost** in your **AJAX** request.

Edit: since you are using POST request should be like this

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/Maps',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: {easting: easting, northing: northing}, //Maps the controller params
    dataType: "json",
    success: function() { alert('Success'); }
    });
```

Comment: Yes I am trying to use [HttpPost], but don't know how?

Comment: Have you tried like @M.Azad said? That should be working

Comment: I have just tried, but it is not hitting my controller method for some reason

Comment: if you are using MVC, dataType should be dataType: "html/text" not json

Comment: @RudyHinojosa that depends on the configuration of the controller